# remix Why do some functions work and others don't

Tags: solidity

[Functions list in Remix IDE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZ698.png)

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.9;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/extensions/ERC20Votes.sol";

contract Token is ERC20Votes {
    constructor(
        string memory _name,
        string memory _symbol,
        uint256 _initialSupply
    ) ERC20(_name, _symbol) ERC20Permit(_name) {
        _mint(msg.sender, _initialSupply);
    }

    // The following functions are overrides required by Solidity.

    function _afterTokenTransfer(
        address from,
        address to,
        uint256 amount
    ) internal override(ERC20Votes) {
        super._afterTokenTransfer(from, to, amount);
    }

    function _mint(address to, uint256 amount) internal override(ERC20Votes) {
        super._mint(to, amount);
    }

    function _burn(
        address account,
        uint256 amount
    ) internal override(ERC20Votes) {
        super._burn(account, amount);
    }
}
```

Please understand Ethereum solidity to help explain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some functions require parameters to be entered.
In your image, CLOCK_MODE works because it's a function with no parameters, you just have to click on it.
The others require parameters. For example, balanceOf expects a wallet address as a parameter, which you enter in the input next to the button